# Solution system $3x \equiv 6\,\textrm{mod}\,\, 12$, $2x \equiv 5\,\textrm{mod}\,\, 7$ , $3x \equiv 1\,\textrm{mod}\,\, 5$

Tags: number-theory, congruences

Have solution the following congruence system?
$$\begin{array}{ccl}
      3x & \equiv & 6\,\textrm{mod}\,\, 12\\
      2x & \equiv & 5\,\textrm{mod}\,\, 7\\
      3x & \equiv & 1\,\textrm{mod}\,\, 5
    \end{array}$$

Point of Interest: This question requires some special handling due to the mixture of factors among the moduli. This is more than the run of the mill Chinese Remainder Theorem problem

Answer (score 1):

Using $\#12$ of [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Congruence.html),

$$2x\equiv5\pmod7\equiv5+7\iff x\equiv6\pmod7\ \ \ \ (1)$$

$$3x\equiv1\pmod5\equiv1+5\iff x\equiv2\pmod5\ \ \ \ (2)$$

$$3x=12k+6\iff x=4k+2\implies x\equiv2\pmod4\ \ \ \ (3)$$

$$(2),(3)\implies x\equiv2\pmod{\text{lcm}(5,4)}\implies x\equiv2\pmod{20}\ \ \ \ (4)$$

Now safely use [CRT](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChineseRemainderTheorem.html) on $(1),(4)$

Answer (score 0):

The congruences simplify to 
$$\left\{ 
\begin{array}{ccc}
x&\equiv& 2\pmod{4} \\
x&\equiv& 6 \pmod{7}\\
x&\equiv& 2 \pmod{5}
\end{array}
\right.$$

The first and third congruences combine to $x\equiv 2 \pmod{20}$.

Then adding the modulus, we have

$\pmod{20}$: $x\equiv 2\equiv 22\equiv 42\equiv 62$

And $62$ satisfies the remaining congruence.  So the solution is $x\equiv 62\pmod{140}$

Comment: That last step is sort of brute force. The usual thing is to apply the Chinese remainder theorem.

Comment: I think of the Chinese Remainder Theorem as asserting the existence of a unique solution (congruence class) that satisfies a system of congruences of the form $x\equiv a_i \pmod{m_i}$ where the $m_i$ are pairwise relatively prime; and the solution is mod the product of the $m_i$.  But I don't think of it as prescribing a method for finding the solution.  For this there are a variety of techniques.  I find adding the modulus to be efficient for small moduli.